# KSoap HTTP 500 Error

Tags: android, wcf, soap, android-ksoap2

I am working on android project and I am trying to implement KSoap library.

I have created a C# Console application that is hosting a C# WCF soap service and I am trying to get android to talk to the soap service.

Below is my C# WCF Service.

```
class SoapServer : ISoapInterface
    {
        public string testSoapFunction()
        {
            return "Hello World";
        }
    }
```

Below is the Soap Interface

```
[ServiceContract]
    public interface ISoapInterface
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string testSoapFunction();
    }
```

Below is how the soap service is started

```
try
            {
                if (Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MONO_STRICT_MS_COMPLIANT") != "yes")
                {
                    Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("MONO_STRICT_MS_COMPLIANT", "yes");
                }
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(soapServerUrl))
                {
                    string message = "Not starting Soap Server: URL or Port number is not set in config file";
                    library.logging(methodInfo, message);
                    library.setAlarm(message, CommonTasks.AlarmStatus.Medium, methodInfo);
                    return;
                }
                baseAddress = new Uri(soapServerUrl);
                host = new ServiceHost(soapHandlerType, baseAddress);
                BasicHttpBinding basicHttpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();

                var meta = new ServiceMetadataBehavior()
                {
                    HttpGetEnabled = true,
                    HttpGetUrl = new Uri("", UriKind.Relative),
                };

                host.Description.Behaviors.Add(meta);

                var debugBehaviour = new ServiceDebugBehavior()
                {
                    HttpHelpPageEnabled = true,
                    HttpHelpPageUrl = new Uri("", UriKind.Relative),
                    IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true

                };

                ServiceEndpoint endpnt = host.AddServiceEndpoint(
                    soapManagerInterface,
                    basicHttpBinding,
                    "EmailServer",
                    new Uri("", UriKind.Relative));


                host.Description.Behaviors.Remove(typeof(ServiceDebugBehavior));
                host.Description.Behaviors.Add(debugBehaviour);
                host.Opened += new EventHandler(host_Opened);
                host.Faulted += new EventHandler(host_Faulted);
                host.Closed += new EventHandler(host_Closed);
                host.UnknownMessageReceived += new EventHandler<UnknownMessageReceivedEventArgs>(host_UnknownMessageReceived);
                host.Open();
```

Below is how I am calling the service via android.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final String soapAction = "http://tempuri.org/ISoapInterface/testSoapFunction";
        final String namespace = "http://tempuri.org/";
        final String methodName = "testSoapFunction";
        final String url = "http://192.168.1.69:8000/CritiMon";
        String resultData = "";

        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                String resultData = "";
                SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnv = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                SoapObject request = new SoapObject(namespace, methodName);

                soapEnv.setOutputSoapObject(request);

                HttpTransportSE http = new HttpTransportSE(url);
                http.debug = true;

                try
                {
                    http.call(soapAction, soapEnv);

                    SoapObject result = (SoapObject)soapEnv.bodyOut;
                    if (result != null)
                    {
                        resultData = result.getProperty(0).toString();
                        Log.d("Soap Result", resultData);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Log.e("Soap", ex.toString());
                }

            }
        }).start();
```

When I run the above code I am getting the following response:

java.io.IOException: HTTP request failed. HTTP Status: 500.

Within the soap server I also fire the unknown message received event handler which contains

```
<v:Envelope xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/
    XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:c="http://s
    chemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/enve
    lope/">
      <v:Header>
        <To v:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addr
    essing/none">http://192.168.1.69:8000/CritiMon</To>
        <Action v:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/
    addressing/none">http://tempuri.org/ISoapInterface/testSoapFunction</Action>
      </v:Header>
      <v:Body>
```

Below is the WSDL from `http://192.168.1.69:8000/CritiMon?wsdl`

```
<wsdl:definitions name="SoapServer" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex" xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata">
<wsdl:types>
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/Imports">
<xsd:import schemaLocation="http://192.168.1.69:8000/CritiMon?xsd=xsd0" namespace="http://tempuri.org/"/>
<xsd:import schemaLocation="http://192.168.1.69:8000/CritiMon?xsd=xsd1" namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"/>
</xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="ISoapInterface_testSoapFunction_InputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:testSoapFunction"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="ISoapInterface_testSoapFunction_OutputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:testSoapFunctionResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="ISoapInterface">
<wsdl:operation name="testSoapFunction">
<wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/ISoapInterface/testSoapFunction" message="tns:ISoapInterface_testSoapFunction_InputMessage"/>
<wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/ISoapInterface/testSoapFunctionResponse" message="tns:ISoapInterface_testSoapFunction_OutputMessage"/>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ISoapInterface" type="tns:ISoapInterface">
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="testSoapFunction">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/ISoapInterface/testSoapFunction" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="SoapServer">
<wsdl:port name="BasicHttpBinding_ISoapInterface" binding="tns:BasicHttpBinding_ISoapInterface">
<soap:address location="http://192.168.1.69:8000/CritiMon/EmailServer"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Comment: if you call ws from browser, is it work?

Comment: Yea I can successfully access from the browser and using the VS WCF Test Client it will successfully return the result

Comment: if you make a easy action in your ws, is it work?

Comment: Sorry not sure what you mean

Comment: i think that you have time out problems, i suggest that you create a simple action in your ws and try to call it when you are debugging it from a device (using 3G intead of Wifi) and check if you recive a time out

Comment: It already is a pretty simple function, just returns a string. I don't believe it is a timeout message as the .net web service fires the unknown message received event handler

Comment: `if (sobre.bodyIn instanceof SoapFault) {
 String str = ((SoapFault) sobre.bodyIn).faultstring;
    Log.i("ERROR ComprobarConexionResult", str);
   } else {
    SoapObject resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapObject) sobre.bodyIn;
    Log.d("WS",
      resultsRequestSOAP.getProperty(
        "ComprobarConexionResult").toString());
    Log.d("ControladorWS.ComprobarConexion", "FINAL");
    retorno = resultsRequestSOAP.getProperty(
      "ComprobarConexionResult").toString();
   }`     I use it to catch ws message

Comment: Thanks I've tried this but the body in is null so it's not helping me :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue finally.

It was an issue with the web service, I was assuming it was an issue with my implementation with Android. There was a type in the soap interface so the android call wasn't finding the function.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the Following

```
soapEnvelope.dotNet = true;
```

If it is not working can you post your WSDL file?

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples")]
public interface ICalculator
{
    [OperationContract]
    string testSoapFunction();
}

final String NAMESPACE = "http://Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples";
final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples/ICalculator/testSoapFunction";
final String METHOD_NAME = "testSoapFunction";

httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(url, 2000);


SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

httpTransport.debug = true;
//soapEnvelope.implicitTypes = true;
soapEnvelope.dotNet = true;
SoapObject soapReq = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(soapReq);


try {
    httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope);
    Log.d("REQ" , httpTransport.requestDump);
    Log.d("RES" , httpTransport.responseDump);

    Object retObj = soapEnvelope.bodyIn;
    Log.d("TEST" , retObj.toString());
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Soap Req:

```
<v:Envelope xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <v:Header />
    <v:Body>
        <testSoapFunction xmlns="http://Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples" id="o0" c:root="1" />
    </v:Body>
</v:Envelope>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I've tried this, but unfortunately getting the same error. I have modified the question to include the wsdl